# Splunk drilldown search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am working on splunk dashboard.  Below is the sample table and query

index="myindex" message="*ApiImpl*" "succeed=true" 
| rex field=message "execution_time=(?.*)"  | table method  response_time | stats  avg(response_time) as "avg", min(response_time) AS "min", max(response_time) As "max" by method

```
**method   avg  max  min**
 create    34   99    22
 update    31   189   21
 delete    30   69    29
```

Now on the result table if I click on 189 in update row. in the new or same window it should open me the same search along with method=update and response_time=189.  Since the table is simple we can make out. But my table is very big when I click on particular cell it should open with the selected filter.

The new search result should open like below. Or should open log event directly with the update method which is taking max responce time 189

```
 **method   avg  max  min**
    update    31   189   21
```

Could you please help me to provide a way like a query or table options to get the new search?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here.  Are you asking for instructions on setting custom options for drill-down in Splunk reports?

Comment: Sorry about that, i forgot to ask the question at the end :-)

Comment: Take a look at Splunk dashboard examples app, it has nice drilldown examples:

https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1603/